# ESXi 6.5 - Root password not working on new installation

Tags: vmware, qemu, esxi, esx

For some strange reason ESXi 6.5 root password isn't working on a new installation. I even tried removing the password by modifying shadow file (following this [guide](https://www.ferroquesystems.com/resource/howto-reset-a-vmware-esxi-root-password/)) and still it doesn't allow me to login with a blank password.

Any idea what could be wrong with a new installation? I'm trying to run ESXi using Qemu.

I've set the password as `password`

[image: screenshot 1]

But during login it says invalid password.

[image: screenshot 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The problem was with Qemu Emulator. I was testing using old version of qemu (3.x) but I can't login when I use 3.x version of Qemu. I then started the ESXi using 7.x version of qemu and I was able to login.